# Help understanding DCT compression for a vector

Tags: pca, data-transformation, dimensionality-reduction

I have multiple 60-dimensional vectors on which I need to apply DCT and reduce to various dimensions. I'm trying to understand  how this happens: https://www.cs.cf.ac.uk/Dave/Multimedia/Topic5.fig_47.gif

In my slides this is all I have about DCT:

-The DCT transform of vector $v$ with dimension $k$ is another vector $u$ with the same dimension $k$

```
v = (v_0, ..., v_k-1)^T
u = (u_0, ..., u_k-1)^T
u_i = a_i SUM[j=0 to k-1](v_j * cos(((2j+1)i*pi)/2k) )
a_0 = sqrt(1/k)     a_i = aqrt(2/k) for i=1, ..., k-1
```

-Then truncate $v$ to $c\le k$ dimensions

But I don't understand how this works, I'm left with another vector $u$ of the same dimension then I can just arbitrarily cut off the end of $v$ to whatever number of dimensions I want? Am I supposed to use the same $u$ vector to reduce all my v vectors(the 60-dimensional vectors I need to reduce)? Or does every $v$ vector have its own $u$ vector? How do the steps in the picture happen?

Answer (score 1):

DCT stands for [Discrete Cosine Transform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discrete_cosine_transform). Actually there are different types of DCT, yet they share the same general properties. Yours appears to be a type-II DCT, which was recently discussed in [Does DCT Type-2 lossless or lossy?](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/27752/does-dct-type-2-lossless-or-lossy).

It is an orthogonal transform, with numerous  signal/image processing applications, for instance  MP3 and  JPEG audio and image commpression. It is used prefered over discrete Fourier transforms for different reasons (optimality  under correlation modeling, speed, realness), and share the  idea of representing data $v$ as a sum  of  sines/cosines with different frequencies. The vector $u$ contains the  multiplicative coefficients for  each of these frequency  indices, and as the same dimension as $v$ (step 2 in your  figure). The  concept used in compression is to reduce the precision on coefficients in $u$, and even discard some of them (step 3 in your  figure). The latter amounts to cancelling  higher frequencies in your data.

Four effects are expected:

- recovering data with cancelled coefficients will yield barely perceptible differences,
- it can even reduce the noise level in your data (like a low-pass filtering),
- the energy and information in your data will be better concentrated,
- last and  foremost, your transformed vectors have fewer samples (you will perform the PCA on the truncated $u$, and add the orthogonal DCT to the projection).

It is important to remember that DCT was designed [(Discrete Cosine Transform, Ahmed, Natarajan & Rao, 1974)](https://www.ic.tu-berlin.de/fileadmin/fg121/Source-Coding_WS12/selected-readings/Ahmed_et_al.__1974.pdf) and compared with the Karhunen-Loève transform (KLT). And the KLT bears similarities with PCA. Loosely speaking, the  DCT is a decorrelating transform, a form of non-adaptive KLT, working for data having a covariance matrix concentrated along the diagonal.

So every  vector $v$ will have its $u$. The difficult exercice is to choose a correct $c\le k$ for all of them, which depends a lot on your data and computation needs. Upon inspection, you can decide that $c=k/2$ or $c=k/4$ suffices. You are lucky enough to have 60 dimensions so you can try a lot of fractions $1/2, 1/3,1/4, 1/5, 1/6$ and check whether you do not get loss in performance with respect to the full data.

A more automated option consists in finding $c$ by computing how much coefficients you need to keep  $90\%$ of the  data energy, for instance. As it is orthogonal, close in mind to tthe KLT, you  can use the method given in [Compute the cumulative energy content for each eigenvector](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principal_component_analysis#Compute_the_cumulative_energy_content_for_each_eigenvector):

> For example, you may want to choose $L$ so that the cumulative energy $g$
>   is above a certain threshold, like 90 percent

The  difference would be that you do not sort by  decreasing eigenvalue (modulus), but by frequency  index.

Comment: +1 nice. Any references for your last sentence?

Comment: If $\sum_i d_i^2 = E$ is the energy in the DCT domain, you can stop at index $i_L$ such that, if   $\sum_{i\le i_L} d_i^2 = g $, $g/E \sim 0.9$. Consider thresholding the cdf of the DCT coefficient distribution.